# Oracle - Union tables with a virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, union

I'm trying to create a new unionized view from an existing view and a table where I want to add a virtual column to the query that, depending on the table/view, will mark a true/false in the virtual column. Something like...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myouterview AS 
SELECT id, field1, field2, ..., 'true' as editable FROM
mytable
union 
SELECT to_number(id), field1, field2, ..., 'false' as Editable FROM
myinnerview
```

With the query above, the rows are duplicating with one entry for true and one for false. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is the view of the same table? You'll only get true/false for the same other values if they exist in both sources. Maybe you know you have some of the same data in both, and you want a not-exists clause in the view part, perheps? We don't know what you're trying to do or what the data represents though, so that's just a guess.

Comment: Post the query of the view. I bet the duplicate rows are from the view. The underlying query is fetching from the the same table.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  You are defining the view and then using the same view in the definition.

Comment: My apologies, it was a mistake in typing things over. I've titled the joining view as "myinnerview" and the resulting view as "myouterview".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myviewouter AS 
SELECT id, field1, field2, ..., 'true' as editable FROM
mytable
union 
SELECT to_number(id), field1, field2, ..., 'false' as Editable FROM
myview B
where not Exists (select 1 from mytable A where A.id=to_number(B.id))
```